# PSQL query to generate value as a array of json array having json with same unique id

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am trying to generate a PSQL query  in a table which having values like id, description and session_unique_id. i want to select the data like a group of json array each of which having json data of each row which having same session_unique_id.

I am expecting result like this.

```
[
 [
  {"id":"1","description":"test","session_unique_id":"123"},
  {"id":"2","description":"test","session_unique_id":"123"},
  {"id":"3","description":"test","session_unique_id":"123"}
 ],
 [
  {"id":"4","description":"test","session_unique_id":"124"},
  {"id":"5","description":"test","session_unique_id":"124"},
  {"id":"6","description":"test","session_unique_id":"124"}],
 [
  {"id":"7","description":"test","session_unique_id":"125"},
  {"id":"8","description":"test","session_unique_id":"125"},
  {"id":"9","description":"test","session_unique_id":"125"}
 ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_jsonb()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to convert rows to jsonb and [`jsonb_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) twice to aggregate the data in nested arrays:

```
select jsonb_agg(unique_id order by session_unique_id)
from (
    select session_unique_id, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(t)) as unique_id
    from my_table t
    group by session_unique_id
    ) t;
```

Test it here: [SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2500e/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Oracle 12.2, you can do it natively:

```
WITH yourtable
     AS (SELECT '1' id, 'test' description, '123' session_unique_id FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '2' id, 'test' description, '123' session_unique_id FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '3' id, 'test' description, '123' session_unique_id FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '4' id, 'test' description, '124' session_unique_id FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '5' id, 'test' description, '124' session_unique_id FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '6' id, 'test' description, '124' session_unique_id FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '7' id, 'test' description, '125' session_unique_id FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '8' id, 'test' description, '125' session_unique_id FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '9' id, 'test' description, '125' session_unique_id FROM DUAL)
SELECT json_arrayagg (obj) yourFinalJSON
  FROM (SELECT json_arrayagg (obj) obj
          FROM (SELECT json_object ('id'     value id,
                    'description' value description,
                    'session_unique_id' value session_unique_id
                ) obj
FROM yourtable) t
group by  json_value(t.obj,'$.session_unique_id'))t
```

Just replace inline view with your table.

Comment: Didn't see that you wrote actually PSQL, but not PL/SQL :)